# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/LimitInputStream

Tags: hadoop, gradle, mapreduce, spring-boot, hadoop-yarn

I am using hadoop version 2.5.0.
Getting this exception while running mapreduce job on this line

```
boolean b = job.waitForCompletion(true);



 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/LimitInputStream
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:467)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1292)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1313)
```

**Updated**
My issue is hadoop is needing LimitInputStream class which is removed from guava16.0 and is upto guava14.0.
On adding org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.7.RELEASE
I get this error .How do I solve this

Comment: are you using any third party jar in your mapreduce

Comment: I am using hadoop-client:2.5.0-cdh5.3.0

Answer (score 1):

You have to force the guava version to 14.0

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```